# Logstash not connecting to Elasticsearch - using Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, elk

I'm trying to create indexes in elasticsearch from a postgresql database.
So I set up docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\theor\desktop\travail\test\test-search\initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - elastic-infrastructure-network

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.11.2
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ELASTIC_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=tidoz!@#6BtAqY7sQSck
      - logger.level=ERROR
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - elastic-infrastructure-network

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.11.2
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - elastic-infrastructure-network

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:8.11.2
    environment:
      - LOG_LEVEL=error
    volumes:
      - ./logstash_configs/logstash-dossiers.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash-dossiers.conf
      - ./logstash_configs/logstash-familytags.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash-familytags.conf
      - C:\Users\theor\desktop\travail\test\test-search\jdbc_driver:/usr/share/logstash/jdbc_driver
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - elastic-infrastructure-network

networks:
  elastic-infrastructure-network:


volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I also installed the jdbc plugin and created configuration files for my indexes:

```
logstash_configs/logstash-dossiers.conf : 
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/jdbc_driver/postgresql.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres"
    jdbc_user => "postgres"
    jdbc_password => "mysecretpassword"
    schedule => "0 * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM dossiers"
  }
    tcp {
        port => 50000
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    user => "elastic"
    password => "tidoz!@#6BtAqY7sQSck"
    index => "dossiers_index"
    document_type => "_doc"
  }
}
```

logstash_configs/logstash-familytags.conf :

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/jdbc_driver/postgresql.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres"
    jdbc_user => "postgres"
    jdbc_password => "mysecretpassword"
    schedule => "0 * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM familytags"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    user => "elastic"
    password => "tidoz!@#6BtAqY7sQSck"
    index => "familytags"
    document_type => "_doc"
  }
}
```

But when I run docker compose, I have the following logs:

ElasticSearch :

```
2023-12-15 14:02:44 Dec 15, 2023 1:02:44 PM sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter <clinit>
2023-12-15 14:02:44 WARNING: COMPAT locale provider will be removed in a future release
2023-12-15 14:02:27 Created elasticsearch keystore in /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore
```

Logstash :

```
2023-12-15 14:02:27 Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
2023-12-15 14:02:42 Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
2023-12-15 14:02:45 [2023-12-15T13:02:45,142][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve Elasticsearch cluster info. {:message=>"No Available connections", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::NoConnectionAvailableError}
2023-12-15 14:02:45 [2023-12-15T13:02:45,150][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
2023-12-15 14:02:45 [2023-12-15T13:02:45,169][ERROR][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Failed to fetch X-Pack information from Elasticsearch. This is likely due to failure to reach a live Elasticsearch cluster.
2023-12-15 14:03:15 [2023-12-15T13:03:15,163][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve Elasticsearch cluster info. {:message=>"No Available connections", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::NoConnectionAvailableError}
2023-12-15 14:03:15 [2023-12-15T13:03:15,164][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
2023-12-15 14:03:45 [2023-12-15T13:03:45,162][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve Elasticsearch cluster info. {:message=>"No Available connections", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::NoConnectionAvailableError}
2023-12-15 14:03:45 [2023-12-15T13:03:45,163][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
2023-12-15 14:02:27 2023/12/15 13:02:27 Setting 'log.level' from environment.
```

EDIT: I can curl the elasticsearch container from Logstash container :  `curl : $ curl -u elastic:tidoz!@#6BtAqY7sQSck -k https://elasticsearch:9200`

```
{
  "name" : "db84df434227",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "U-RFYDsMT2isrc3C8xpPTg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.11.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "76013fa76dcbf144c886990c6290715f5dc2ae20",
    "build_date" : "2023-12-05T10:03:47.729926671Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.8.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Don't understand why cause same values are used in .conf files :

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/jdbc_driver/postgresql.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres"
    jdbc_user => "postgres"
    jdbc_password => "mysecretpassword"
    schedule => "0 * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM familytags"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://elasticsearch:9200"]
    user => "elastic"
    password => "tidoz!@#6BtAqY7sQSck"
    cacert => "/usr/share/logstash/http_ca.crt"
    index => "familytags"
    document_type => "_doc"
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_verification => true
  }
}
```

I've tried disabling SSL and re-enabled it but nothing works.
I'm a little lost, I don't really know how to solve this problem, if you have a solution I'm interested.

I am trying to create elastic search index for specified table of my postgres database and insert the data of the table into their corresponding index into elastic search.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Theo.

Comment: Can you curl the elasticsearch from the logstash instance ? `curl http(s)://elasticsearch:9200` what does it say ?

Comment: curl : $ curl -u elastic:tidoz!@#6BtAqY7sQSck -k https://elasticsearch:9200
{
  "name" : "db84df434227",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "U-RFYDsMT2isrc3C8xpPTg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.11.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "76013fa76dcbf144c886990c6290715f5dc2ae20",
    "build_date" : "2023-12-05T10:03:47.729926671Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.8.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"

Comment: Could you force http or https see the one elasticsearch accepts ? We just proved `logstash` can talk to `elasticsearch`

Comment: How could i do this? Because it is already forced inside the .conf files

Comment: In logstash.yml do you have xpack.monitoring.enabled set to true and if so what is the value of xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts?

Comment: i don't have a logstash.yml file, i only have files specified in docker-compose, or you mean a logstash.yml file inside the logstash container ?